# C++ Read istream into string with exceptions

Tags: c++, strings, stream, exception

Did I cover all the bases? Can this be improved (best practice)?

Edit... I've come up with some improvements. When I tried edit the code, the software complained about too much code and too little blather (paraphrasing). So, here I am blathering. When I have blathered enough, the code below will be the new stuff.

```
//#include <libdj/istream.h>

#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace dj {
    inline
    void append_istream_onto_string(std::istream& inp, std::string &outp) {
        // Uses inp.seekg(), and inp.tellg() to determine size
        // Throws (std::) invalid_argument, runtime_error, bad_alloc, length_error
        if (!inp.good()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument
              ("Input stream is not valid. (read_istream_into_string)");
        }
        if (!inp.seekg(0, std::ios::end)) {
            throw std::runtime_error
            ("Cannot deduce length of input stream. (read_istream_into_string)");
        }
        outp.reserve(outp.size() + inp.tellg()); // Throws bad_alloc and length_error
        if (!inp.seekg(0, std::ios::beg)) {
            throw std::runtime_error
              ("Input stream seek failed. (read_istream_into_string)");
        }
        outp.append((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inp)),
            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    }

    inline
    std::string to_string(std::istream& inp) {
        std::string ret;
        append_istream_onto_string(inp, ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream inp("junk.txt");

    std::string buffer;
    buffer = "// junk.txt\n";
    try {
        //dj::append_istream_onto_string(inp, buffer);
        buffer = dj::to_string(inp);
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are awful. Don't use them. (Joking, but I wish I had a viable alternative to recommend for basic file input. C++ is pathetic in this area.)

- [code:] `tellg()` returns a signed type, with -1 as an error value. You might like to check that, and then `static_cast` it before using it in `reserve()`.
- [code:] Using `std::string::resize()` and `std::istream::read()` to copy from the stream might be faster than using `std::string::append()` with `std::istreambuf_iterator`s.
- [design(bug?):] Seeking to the end of the file like that may not work. On Windows, for example, if a file is opened in text mode, the ctrl-z (alt026) character is treated as the end of the file (even though it isn't). As I understand it, [you have to use `ignore()` to find the real end of the file instead](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/how-to-read-an-entire-file-into-memory-in-cpp/).
- [design:] I doubt it's worth it to create a function to append a string directly. Loading into a string, then appending is probably fast enough. (What if you want to prepend or insert... suddenly you need more functions that basically do the same thing).
- Write unit tests! Something like this needs a whole bunch of tests that save a string to a file, then load a string and compare the results (binary mode, text mode, special characters, etc.).

The [whole article in the link above](http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/09/how-to-read-an-entire-file-into-memory-in-cpp/) is useful, but the summary section at the end describes 3 reasonable alternatives for reading from a file stream:

- Put the `istream`'s `rdbuf` into a stringstream, then use the `.str()` function to get a string. This involves extra copying, but is simplest, and should be quick enough.
- Use `.ignore()` to find the end of the file, then read the whole thing at once. No extra copies in memory (good for large files), but involves reading the file twice.
- Read chunks into a `std::deque` and then copy. Works where it's not possible to seek in the stream.

Comment: Good stuff. ...

Comment: I have hated std::streams since before they were made standard. I intend to act upon your criticism.  I appreciate it enormously. Watch this space.